# Magento - Category Thumbnails - How to use SVG?

Tags: magento

I cannot upload **SVG-images as Category-Thumbnail-pictures in Magento** (CE, 1.8). Just "normal" image-formats like **jpg** or **png** seem to work. 
Does anybody have an idea?

[image: magento-backend]

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite or modify this Model

> class Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Attribute_Backend_Image
>
> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php

In line 60

```
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png','svg')); // add the file type SVG to the allowed extension array.
```

It will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Soltion is:

> class Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Attribute_Backend_Image

rewrite file

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php

update code

```
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png','svg'));
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
// Avoid Validation for SVG
// $uploader->addValidateCallback(
//     Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image::NAME,
//     new Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image(),
//     "validate"
// );
```

And boom , you are done!!